# Open a file with webhdfs in docker container

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose, webhdfs

first, sorry for my english.

I have a problem when i try to open a .mp4 file with webhdfs. I use the bde2020 image for hadoop. When i try in firefox, http://localhost:9870/webhdfs/v1/path/to/file/video.mp4?op=GETFILESTATUS, i have a good answer. But when i try http://localhost:9870/webhdfs/v1/path/to/file/video.mp4?op=OPEN, that loading a lot and the URL redirect is : http://id_container_datanode:9864/webhdfs/v1/path/to/file/video.mp4?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:9000&offset=0
I don't understand the problem, and why i have an answer with GETFILESTATUS and not OPEN.
I hope i am clear, if not, you can ask me and i reformulate.

Here some code, i change nothing from the image bde2020, i just share a folder in namenode :

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
      - share:/share:consistent
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:
  share:
      external: true
```

hadoop.env

```
CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user=root
CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_hosts=*
CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_groups=*
CORE_CONF_io_compression_codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec

HDFS_CONF_dfs_webhdfs_enabled=true
HDFS_CONF_dfs_permissions_enabled=false
HDFS_CONF_dfs_namenode_datanode_registration_ip___hostname___check=false

YARN_CONF_yarn_log___aggregation___enable=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_log_server_url=http://historyserver:8188/applicationhistory/logs/
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_recovery_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_store_class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_scheduler_class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler
YARN_CONF_yarn_scheduler_capacity_root_default_maximum___allocation___mb=8192
YARN_CONF_yarn_scheduler_capacity_root_default_maximum___allocation___vcores=4
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_fs_state___store_uri=/rmstate
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_system___metrics___publisher_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_hostname=resourcemanager
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_address=resourcemanager:8032
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_scheduler_address=resourcemanager:8030
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_resource__tracker_address=resourcemanager:8031
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_generic___application___history_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_hostname=historyserver
YARN_CONF_mapreduce_map_output_compress=true
YARN_CONF_mapred_map_output_compress_codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_resource_memory___mb=16384
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_resource_cpu___vcores=8
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_disk___health___checker_max___disk___utilization___per___disk___percentage=98.5
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_remote___app___log___dir=/app-logs
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_aux___services=mapreduce_shuffle

MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_framework_name=yarn
MAPRED_CONF_mapred_child_java_opts=-Xmx4096m
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_memory_mb=4096
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_memory_mb=8192
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_java_opts=-Xmx3072m
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_java_opts=-Xmx6144m
MAPRED_CONF_yarn_app_mapreduce_am_env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
```

Dockerfile for namenode

```
FROM bde2020/hadoop-base:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8

MAINTAINER Ivan Ermilov <ivan.s.ermilov@gmail.com>

HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -f http://localhost:9870/ || exit 1

ENV HDFS_CONF_dfs_namenode_name_dir=file:///hadoop/dfs/name
RUN mkdir -p /hadoop/dfs/name
VOLUME /hadoop/dfs/name

ADD run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod a+x /run.sh

EXPOSE 9870

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you provide some code snippets as well? That makes it easier to understand what  is happening in the backend

Comment: I edit my first post, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The file needs to be exposed by the `datanode`, the API does internally a redirect from the `namenode` to the `datanode`. In that sense you need to open the port and set the hostname to work.
I have to say that Aitor pointed the solution, but without understanding what's happening is difficult to understand his answer.

```
  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    hostname: localhost
    ports:
      - 9864:9864
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
```

From the documentation, you can see at: [Open and read file](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#OPEN)

There will be a redirect to the content of the file served by octet-stream by the `datanode`:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Location: http://<DATANODE>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=OPEN...
Content-Length: 0
```

Hope it helps everyone with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you add the following line for the datanode service in your docker-compose will works:

hostname: localhost

Also expose the port - 9864:9864 .

Regards,

Aitor

Comment: Hi Aitor, welcome to SO, thank you for the answer. It might help people to include some information about why this solves the problem.