# Hadoop: How can i resolve the error "Could'n upload the file" in docker container

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose, hdfs

Hadoop was run on the local machine with [`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). And tried to upload a file to HDFS from the Web UI, but the following results occurred:

> Couldn't upload the file bar.txt

[image]

#### Symptoms

- folders can be created on the Web UI.
- browser devtools fails to network request

[image]

#### Attempt 1

checked and found that the network call failed. Wokred with this reference [Open a file with webhdfs in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847418/open-a-file-with-webhdfs-in-docker-container) and added the following to `services.datanode.ports` into `docker-compose.yml`. But the symptoms were the same.

```yaml
services:
  ...

  datanode:
    ...
    ports:
      - 9864:9864
```

Your help can be of great help to me.

Comment: Add: request url (datanode) `9a51765b27b4` was docker container id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File uploads to WebHDFS require an HTTP redirect (first it creates the file handle in HDFS, then you upload the file to that place).

Your host doesn't know the container service names, so you will see `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

One possible solution is to edit your `/etc/hosts` file to include the namenode container ID to point at `127.0.0.1`, however the better way would simply be do `docker-compose exec` into a container with an HDFS client, and run `hadoop fs -put` commands

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When creating the container, put the `hosts` file into the volume?

Solved it using the webhdfs REST API before saw your answer. -- I don't need uploading on UI --

Comment: The hosts file is meant to be used outside of the container. Docker has its own methods for modifying the DNS entries inside containers

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Using the bridge network, I understood that every time the container id changes, I had to change the hosts file. If used host network mode on Linux, I don't have to change the hosts file separately because don't have a subnet?

Comment: You shouldn't be referring to any container id, anyway, only the service name or the `hostname` defined in the compose file

Comment: Can anyone help in how to edit /etc/hosts so that the container ID points to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Vish _the better way would simply be do `docker-compose exec` into a container with an HDFS client, and run `hadoop fs -put` commands_